# What is stopping SQL Server 2014 from using just a one 2 core license?

Tags: sql-server-2014, licensing, cpu-cores

Business is trying to sort out buying SQL Server core license.

as with business, price.

So question is asked, why can we not just buy that 2 core license.

I know from reading, minimum of 4 core license need per physical processor.

But what is actully stopping SQL Server 2014 from saying - oh u have a license okay, i will run, or is the Software actually "smart" and detect only 2 license in use, so no wont run.

Or is this one of the "Auditing" things when checked on?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install SQL server using the core licensing model, you will see the server version listed as such:

> Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise: Core-based Licensing (64-bit)

The product key doesn't tell the server how many cores to use, it will use them all by deafult.  To be compliant with the licensing regulations, you must license all cores in the machine, even if you only have a single CPU, you must purchase 4 core licenses (setting an affinity mask to try and get around this requirement is not allowed by the licensing terms).

This will be picked up in an audit if you are "lucky" enough to get one.